# How to totally remove Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, delete, uninstall

I've got Ubuntu on my laptop and I want to completely remove it so I have no OS on it. 
Google provides no answers which would be relative, they are only like "How to delete Ubuntu if you have Windows/and then install Windows".
My Ubuntu is 20.04, as I remember. If possible, tell me the detailed steps. 
**Thanks in advance!**
Additional: The possible way is to format disk, but I have no idea how to do it because Ubuntu don't let me to.

Comment: The steps applied to deleting a distro as part of a hard disk also apply to the whole disk that you want to get rid of. If you have difficulties understand specific steps, please add those parts to the question.

Comment: What is a computer without OS good for? You can format your disks if you want to remove everything, but note that it will be hard to use the computer afterwards.

Comment: That's the problem, I have no idea how to format disk because it just doesn't let me to do it in Ubuntu.

Comment: @eblock Done, added

Comment: Should be fairly easy from a live CD or booting a from a USB stick...

Comment: Kusalananda, can you explain what should I use and how? I am kind of newbie in this, I only know how to boot from USB

Comment: The answer to this will depend on why you are doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Boot your system using an Ubuntu liveCD / liveUSB image or installation media.
- Rather than launching the Ubuntu installer, instead launch `fdisk` or another partition editor such as `parted` in your preferred a Terminal program to alter the partition table of the disk in question (e. g. `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`).  If you're unclear how to use the partition editor, in another Terminal window  consult the manual with `man`.
- Delete all partitions from the hard disk in question (e. g. `/dev/sda`).  **Be certain you're operating on the correct medium.**
- Write the changes to the disk.
- If you also want to wipe the boot sector, run the following command:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

Be advised this will remove all partition information, but is *not* a "disk wipe" or "secure delete".  If you want to truly be certain that data can not be recovered, the most effective tool to use is a hammer.

Comment: Where do I get liveCD iso file? Sorry if this is a dumb question. And after it, can I use Rufus to make USB drive out of ISO?

Comment: If you have an optical drive (e. g. a CD/DVD burner drive), you can use `dd` to burn the image to disk.  If your system is still running Ubuntu currently, a guide to a bootable flash drive creator can be found at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: `parted` might be a better choice than `fdisk`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have only one drive in your laptop. Just execute

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=128M
```

and wait. It will delete **everything** on the first drive (including other operating systems and user-data). The system will crash sooner or later, so this is not a perfectly safe method in sense of data security.